# SQL Reporting Service (2012) Count Duplicates

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

i have to count all duplicate caller_ids in a telephone system

My Table look like this:

```
|call_id |calling_id|
|      1 | 4711     |  
|      2 | 4711     |  
|      3 | 4712     |  
|      4 | 4713     |  
|      5 | 4713     |
```

The result shoul be:
Multiple dial outs: 4
Because the 4711 and the 4713 are called at least two times.

First i create a child Group by calling_id, hide the row. The group has the name "DuplicateCallId".

```
=SUM(IIF(Count(Fields!called_id.Value, "called_id")>=2,Count(Fields!called_id.Value, "called_id"),0))
```

My result is:
[image]

Not Bad, but:

- 4711 and 4713 are ok, but I don't need a row for 4712. How can I remove it.
- The 5 is the SUM. This row is not part of the group caller_id. i try the same exprtession with another scope name. What I need is just a sum of the expression above, how can i do that?

Do you have a solution for the challenge, how to count duplicate values?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do each called ID's counts in the query itself.

```
SELECT calling_id
    ,count(call_id)
FROM TABLENAME
GROUP BY calling_id
HAVING count(call_id) > 1;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/99c55/2/5)

Then in the report itself, sum values in that column.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but the result set contains more than this 2 columns. That means, I have to work with two indipendent datasets (not my favorite). i preffer to solve it in reporting service.